# Nested query in mysql in messages

Tags: mysql

This query returns the result in ASC order, Please i need to retrieve the results in DESC order in the nested shape because of other usage
OR
I need to retrieve the last sent message for each user

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY messages.ID DESC ) messages GROUP BY From_User_ID
```

Comment: I suspect what you're looking for is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1 but your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat your order by in the outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY ID DESC ) messages ORDER BY messages.ID DESC
```

Edit:

Following the comment, you'd still just reference the table once, and the order by in the outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM  (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY ID DESC )
GROUP BY messages.From_User_ID -- You may have to group by additional fields as you're selecting all
ORDER BY messages.From_User_ID DESC
```

Comment: I need to make outer group  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY ID DESC ) messages GROUP BY From_User_ID

Comment: Are you trying to get the highest ID for each `From_User_Id`?

Comment: @OmarTawba Update your question to show what you're really trying to do. Because the query you posted won't do what you said it does.

Comment: I want to retrieve the last message that each user sent, thanks for your help

Comment: Okay, can you please do as @Barmar suggested and edit your question to clarify? Can you also provide sample data? I think I've answered the question posed at the start. I'm guessing from your further comment that you want a: having Max(date) clause but there's no way of telling without seeing the data.

Comment: Ah, great! Glad I could at least help point you in the right direction with the SQL! What was your final query?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the "Messages" table has a field called "x". So you want the result of aggregate function sum (as an example of usage of "Group by"):

```
SELECT t1.From_User_ID, sum(t1.x) as sumOfX 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM messages
    ) as t1
GROUP BY t1.From_User_ID
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

You can replace "sum" by "count", "avg", "min" or "max".